# Automatically Modify URL in Firefox

Tags: url, firefox, firefox-addon

I can access various scientific journals for free through my university's internal site. However, I often find an interesting article through a Google search, and have to manually modify the url to access the free version.

For example:

*www.nature.com/SomethingSpecifyingTheArticle*

needs to be

*www.nature.com.**ExtraPart**/SomethingSpecifyingTheArticle*

The **ExtraPart** gives me free access to the article via my university credentials. I can manually add it to the URL, but I am looking for a way to do it automatically.

It always goes at the end of the root URL like this:

*www.science.com.**ExtraPart**/SomethingSpecifyingTheArticle* 
*prl.aps.org.**ExtraPart**/SomethingSpecifyingTheArticle*

Is it possible to automate this? Maybe using some script and Greasemonkey?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nothing; I don't know how to write scripts for Firefox, but any help in getting there would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, neither of what you write are questions - so no, those commands are not my questions.

My questions was in the first place: Is it possible? (Feel free to refer to my first post to verify this).

Secondly, if affirmative: How can this be done? 

As mentioned above, I don't know anything about scripting in Firefox, so I have no idea what the extent of a script doing this would be. If it is a one week project, I obviously don't ask for anyone to do this for me. If it is a five minute (or similar) project, then I hope someone would help me solving it.

Comment: Thank you for the pedagogical link.

Answer (score 3):

A better and more generic solution:

Add a bookmark (in any browser) with the following address:

javascript:(function(){%20var%20curloc%20=%20window.location.toString();%20var%20newloc%20=%20curloc.substring(0,%20curloc.indexOf("/",%208))%20+%20".ExtraPart"%20+%20curloc.substring(curloc.indexOf("/",%208));%20location.href=newloc;%20})()

When you are on the page, where you wish to add the ExtraPart at the end of the root URL, click this bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

URL Swap Run (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/url-swap/) essentially does what I want - the only bad thing about it is that I have to manually add the individual journals as rules in the preferences, but that's not a big issue.